# Access Popup menu in eclipse created with Menu(Control parent) constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, popup, eclipse-rcp

I have Control, let's say `ImageHyperlink imageHyperlink` on which I have popup menu created like this: `Menu menu = new Menu(imageHyperlink);`
Is there any way to access that menu (and its menu items) programmatically assuming that i have access to imageHyperlink?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common error to assume a constructed `Menu` is in any way associated with the `Control` specified in the constructor! The constructor in question is defined as

```
public Menu (Control parent) {
    this (checkNull (parent).menuShell (), SWT.POP_UP);
}
```

so with other words: the menu is associated with the `Shell` of the control, not the control itself.

Before a `Menu` acts as the popup menu of a specific `Control`, the menu *must* explicitly be set as the menu of the control with

```
imageHyperlink.setMenu(menu);
```

When this has been done, then menu can always be retrieved with `imageHyperlink.getMenu()`.